# Handling error codes in Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: android, google-identity-toolkit

I am using Google Identity Toolkit for login into app I am working on. The problem is, when I get an error (INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE, some error codes without explanations and so on), the Toast with an error code appears. I tried to use a custom UI Manager but then I have to handle all the screens and cannot use the default ones. I am pretty happy with everything beside handling error codes.
So, the question is, how could I actually handle all of the error codes as I don't get them in sign in callbacks? Toast is also problem and I want to get rid of it, but I think I have to use custom UI manager, as I mentioned earlier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this version you need to use the custom UI manager to avoid the Toast. However, if you constantly see the INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE error, most likely there are some configuration mismatch between your app and your Google Developers Console project.

Comment: I know about INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE, that is the other problem but it was solved. However, If I use UI manager should I create my own layouts? Is there a way to use default Google's popup layouts while using UI manager?